# How to require password for redownloading apps from App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-appstore

Little kids keep redownloading deleted apps, and I can't stop them, because apparently Apple doesn't ask for a password to redownload deleted app, it only requires password when installing new apps.

The only way to stop this travesty is to logout from my Apple ID.

This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Parental Controls : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304#prevent-purchases Please ask a question if this article doesn't answer your query. Also, for reference: [How to ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)